# Using http service and its client in the same computer

Tags: http, service, firewall

I am going to develop a http service and an application as its client which both of them are in the same computer.

I have 2 questions :

1. Might any firewall block this application?
2. If so, how can i solve the problem?

Tanx in advance.

Comment: This doesn't really merit a full answer. Yes, a firewall may block it **depending on how it is configured** and if it does you should **change the configuration**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the firewall will not block the application.

You can use 127.0.0.1:80 to access the local http service.  80 is the default port number and you can drop it.  Alternatively, you can use something like http://localhost to test it.